# Bad performance in Django / Apache

Tags: django, apache, postgresql, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi

I have written this view that is supposed to be fast and simple, but in reality it takes way too much time and basically hogs my server's CPUs.

It's written in django-rest-framework and basically does the following:

- look up DB object from query parameters
- update some fields in db object
- save object
- find any detail records for the object
- return json-encoded detail records

The view is written as part of APIView.post() handler.

Profiling the function itself offers the following:

- fetch takes 2 - 5 ms
- update takes 1 ms
- fetch details takes 3 - 7 ms
- apache itself reports some **30-40 ms MORE** than the profiled function itself (if function reports total time 10ms, apache (access.log) will report some 40ms. The added time seems to be there for all queries.

netdata (looking at postgres page) says that all fetches are done from RAM.
I have a 2 CPU machine serving the entire app.

The 2 CPUs are loaded for the entire Apache-reported time, meaning that average function serving time is 40 ms, I get 100% load at 50 queries per second. Obviously, my target is MUCH more than 50 queries per second. As the core function takes only ~10ms, I figure the CPUs should be loaded 20%, not 100%.

top shows that almost all CPU time is consumed in wsgi process. Apache workers only consumes some 2 - 3% CPU, same for postgres.

I have tried to verify whether it's Django's context processors adding the overhead, but they are not, at least not on my development machine (manage.py runserver): local queries from the same machine incur no overhead whatsoever regardless of the number of active context processors (only the default ones at that).

I tried tweaking apache / mod_wsgi parameters, but nothing changed the situation - it's really only 50 requests per second against a small dataset, everything is in RAM --- it just takes a HUGE amount of time.

I'd add configuration files but I'm not sure they are at all relevant, so if they are, let me know what to append.

What am I missing?

@Graham Dumpleton:
**mpm_event.conf:**

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers             2
        MinSpareThreads          25
        MaxSpareThreads          75
        ThreadLimit              64
        ThreadsPerChild          250
        MaxRequestWorkers        1500
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

**site-enabled:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ....
    WSGIDaemonProcess mgmt-server display-name=wsgi-main processes=2 threads=50 python-path=/home/myuser/mgmt-server
    WSGIProcessGroup mgmt-server

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myuser/mgmt-server/ServerCfg/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory "/home/myuser/mgmt-server/ServerCfg">
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I do not know what you mean by veryfying whether app is running in daemon processes. WSGIRestrictEmbedded is not explicitly set in site configuration

**Edit2:**
Further testing shows that the culprit is definitely somewhere in Django code: When profiling wsgi.py, it clearly shows that the vast majority of the overhead is between wsgi.py and target API function.
Proceeding (again) with removing middleware to see where that takes me.

**Edit 3:**
Implementing pgbouncer showed no improvement despite connection time decreasing considerably in test (numbers below are in seconds per 1000 connections):

```
pgbouncer 0.2007670805323869
socket 4.6464033296797425
ip 9.120775469928049
```

It's obviously not DB connection time. Proceeding with detailed profiling.

**Edit 4:**
Don't know whether it's more appropriate to post this into answer or here, but I decided to go for here :)

After numerous optimisations and tweaks I managed to get the entire thing to somewhere around 25 ms per call. This is still HUGE, but I'm at a loss as to how to remedy this since I need the indexes.

Profiling function by function, I found there are three significant CPU burners:

1. 27% My code fetching & updating the record
2. 50% Transaction.commit (with transaction.atomic():) - of the above
3. 23% Django & rest-framework middleware, most notably CommonMiddleware, resolver.resolve (URL matching) and lazy-loading session.user object for authentication. All together some 6ms

I'm completely perplexed why fetching & updating from a table with 550 records (not millions, 550 without any additional zeroes behind there) would take so much time, even if the table in question has 5 indexes. This is all a few pages-in-DB affair. The same app also has a table with millions of records that have frequent inserts only (a log table) and that table is performing much more admirably.

I'm attempting to run vaccuum on it right now and if it helps, I'll try to set up auto-vaccuum as well. More than that I don't know what to do save introducing memcached and working around this stupid issue with the DB.

**Edit 5:**
Vacuum did not help.

**Edit 6:**
Experimenting with delayed WAL settings:

- synchronous_commit=off
- wal_sync_method=fsync (was fastest in pg_test_fsync)
- wal_buffers=16MB (was this value even before as shared_buffers = 512MB)
- <s>wal_writer_delay=500ms</s>
- <s>commit_delay=1000</s>
- <s>commit_siblings=5</s>

(<s>I'm not really sure about</s> Forget the last three, tweaking without knowledge may decrease performance considerably)
These changes increased my pgbench results from 72TPS to 1500TPS.

This moves transaction.commit() time back to zero. My function now takes only its "original time" where I wasn't careful about profiling transaction time. However, the entire request still takes the same expanded time.

My guess: this is because Django releases connection on request served and that triggers a forced write, possibly? Proceeding to play with CONN_MAX_AGE setting. Possibly reinstalling pgbouncer.

**Edit7:**

Final report:

Reinstalling pgbouncer now results in most of the requests being server within 15ms. I guess this is the theoretical limit of what Django with some DB operations can do. 6 - 8ms for Django handlers, 6 - 8ms for my own function. This increases my serving capacity to around 120 requests per second (dual core CPU).

Proceeding with some type of WebSockets solution which will allow me to pool updates and reduce Django processing overhead.

Comment: What Apache MPM are you using? What Apache MPM settings? What is ``MaxRequestsPerChild`` set to? What mod_wsgi mode are you using? If using mod_wsgi daemon mode, with what configuration? Have you verified your application is actually running in mod_wsgi daemon mode processes if that is wanted? Are you setting ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded On`` to ensure embedded mode isn't enabled?

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton: updated with relevant configuration details

Comment: WSGIRestrictEmbedded On is now in wsgi_mod.load configuration file. No change.

Comment: Added code to print out "mod_wsgi.process_group" environment variable. It correctly printed out the process group. I suppose that means daemon mode is working?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the steps you went through. It is a good example of how a specific web server is not usually the issue.

Comment: I didn't think it would be. I'm guessing I'm not the first guy with Apache / mod_wsgi deployment, so I kept on digging. I am somewhat surprised that Django's overhead would be as high though. I really though I'd be safe at least until somewhere around 1000 requests / s. Your comments did eliminate a few of the possible research directions though, so thanks for saving my time. I much appreciate it, especially if it's done by one as established as yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Main thing that concerns me with that configuration is `threads=50`. Python doesn't handle well a large number of concurrent threads if they are CPU intensive.

As background as to why, I suggest you watch my talk about this problem at:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGleKfigMsk

Other things I would have been looking for are continuous recycling of daemon processes. You aren't though using any options which would cause that. Constant restarts would be a problem due to needing to always load the application again.

You haven't said anything to suggest you are seeing process restarts, but you could set `LogLevel info` in Apache configuration then mod_wsgi will log details about restarts so you can confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your insight so far. Please note that "threads = 50" was an interim value while I was experimenting to see where the culprit is (i moved it back to 12 now). I have now located the culprit somewhere AFTER Apache / mod_wsgi stack, but I am yet to pinpoint it. Will have to profile manually function by function since adding cProfile waters out the culprit into oblivion.